# How to import cookieMaster (or any installed external node package)?

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cookies

I have an angular - ionic application which fails to store cookie values when deployed to iOS. I'm testing this on an iOS simulator.

I've read that this is a known issue which is related to web kit.
There are many npm packages which attempt to bypass this issue.

I am trying this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cookiemaster

but I'm not sure how to use this cookieMaster service.
As in

`cookieMaster.getCookieValue...`

How do I import this cookieMaster to use in my service? Not sure how to reference the package as an import directive.

Comment: From the docs, it looks like `cookieMaster` is just a global.

Comment: @johnborges I get this error: ERROR in src/app/services/authentication/authentication-service.service.ts:34:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'cookieMaster'.

Comment: Any solution for this ? I am facing the same error : Cannot find name 'cookieMaster'

Comment: i get this error : Property 'cookieMaster' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'